# How to read Json file(array values) and print values using shell script

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jenkins-cli

I have a Jenkins Job that prints a list of elements either in Json or Text format,I am trying to setup a Jenkins job that would print the first element ,second element..... form a JSON or TEXT.And I wanted to assign it to a variable so i can retrieve any element using its number, 
"ex:- array[4]"
  I am looking to read the output and print these values in shell.

and I am trying to use different ways from online to get to ,using  arrays ,using echo and yet looking for other way, any documents or any information would be helpful for me to go through.

the output on Jenkins in JSON looks like:-

```
[
"Danilo"
]
[
    "Kevin"
]
```

the output on Jenkins in TEXT looks like:-

```
Danilo
Kevin
```

Any information or a place would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: The output seems like two JSONs, not a single one.

Comment: oh sorry I am using --output json and --output text in jenkins, so I am showing both outputs . but required is the first elements either using json with shell or text file with shell.

Comment: Don't try to roll your own JSON parser, use something like [tag:jq]

Comment: I am using something like "-- query "reservations[].instances.privateipadress" --output json" so I am not storing this value either in a file, i am just printing it . so how to get the first element from the above query . This is what i am trying to get . any idea or a thought that I am missing.

Comment: I have found a way to read them, and posted my answer. thank you for the suggestion .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used for loop by getting the count of the words.And the output I stored in a txt file not json.

so i used

```
c1=$(wc-w < file.txt)
```

***file.txt*** is the name of the file used to input these values from example Danilo,Kevin,and **c1** gives number of word count which is **2** in this example

Now I used for loop:

```
for i in `seq 1 $c1`

do

export Name$i=$(sed -n "$i"p file.txt)

done
```

this way we will get the output as Name1=Danilo and Name2=Kevin as I am exporting the value each time in the loop.